# Fetch all images at once and show 360 product view in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-redux

I have already written a component that enables 360 product views for users. Users can interact with image (rotate to the right or left). This Component works well when images are from local files.

I want to fetch images from Cloudinary and render them. A product may have 100+ images so I want to show loader till all images are loaded. Once done image will render and when the user rotates new image is rendered. I was also looking for npm lib that takes care of loading and rendering images.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Row, Space, Typography, Image } from "antd";
import { Md3DRotation } from "react-icons/md";
// You can play with this to adjust the sensitivity
// higher values make mouse less sensitive
const pixelsPerDegree = 1;

class React360 extends Component {
  static defaultProps = { dir: "puma", numImages: 83 };

  state = {
    dragging: false,
    imageIndex: 0,
    dragStartIndex: 0,
    images: [],
    show360: false,
    imgs:null
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp, false);
    // document.addEventListener("touchstart", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    // document.addEventListener("touchend", this.handleMouseUp, false);
   
  };


  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp, false);
    // document.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    // document.removeEventListener("touchend", this.handleMouseUp, false);
  };

  handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    //   console.log("e.screenX",Math.round(e?.touches?.[0]?.clientX))
    e.persist();
    this.setState((state) => ({
      dragging: true,
      dragStart: e.screenX || Math.round(e?.touches?.[0]?.clientX),
      dragStartIndex: state.imageIndex,
    }));
  };

  handleMouseUp = () => {
    this.setState({ dragging: false });
  };

  updateImageIndex = (currentPosition) => {
    let numImages = this.props.numImages;
    const pixelsPerImage = pixelsPerDegree * (360 / numImages);
    const { dragStart, imageIndex, dragStartIndex } = this.state;
    // pixels moved
    let dx = (currentPosition - dragStart) / pixelsPerImage;
    let index = Math.floor(dx) % numImages;

    if (index < 0) {
      index = numImages + index - 1;
    }
    index = (index + dragStartIndex) % numImages;
    // console.log(index, dragStartIndex, numImages)
    if (index !== imageIndex) {
      this.setState({ imageIndex: index === 0 ? 1 : index });
    }
  };

  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    //   console.log("handleMouseMove",this.state.dragging)
    console.log("screenX", Math.round(e?.touches?.[0]?.clientX));
    if (this.state.dragging) {
      this.updateImageIndex(e.screenX || Math.round(e?.touches?.[0]?.clientX));
    }
  };

  preventDragHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  renderImage = () => {
    const { imageIndex, images } = this.state;


    return (
      <>
       
        <div className="react360">
           <img
           
            alt=""
            src={
               require(`../../assets/puma_opti/IMG_00${
                 imageIndex > 9 ? imageIndex : "0" + imageIndex
               }.JPG`).default
             }
            
          /> 
        
        </div>
        <Row justify="center" style={{ marginTop: "1.5em" }}>
          <Space>
            <Md3DRotation size={25} color="#8C8C8C" />
            <Typography.Title
              level={5}
              type="secondary"
              style={{ fontFamily: "Gilroy" }}
              className="helptext-360"
            >
              Drag to view 360 degrees
            </Typography.Title>
          </Space>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className="react-360-img"
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onDragStart={this.preventDragHandler}
        // onTouchStart={this.handleMouseMove}
        onTouchStart={this.handleMouseDown}
        onTouchMove={this.handleMouseMove}
        onTouchEnd={this.handleMouseUp}
      >
        {this.renderImage()}
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.For library you can use React Loading Skeleton : `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton`
2.If you want to display loading when you get data you have to add condition to your jsx, for instance:

```
fetchData.loading?(
   return <Skeleton/>
  ):(
  <div className="react360">
   data.map(res=>{
    <img 
      alt="" 
      src={
      require(`../../assets/puma_opti/IMG_00${
       imageIndex > 9 ? imageIndex : "0" + imageIndex}.JPG`).default
      }
    /> 
  }))
 </div>
```

N.B: fetchdata is the status of your API call (if is loading or successful), data is data obtained from API.